# Akeneo 3.2 not loading issue | Ubuntu 16

Tags: akeneo

I Installed Akeneo 3.2 on the following system config:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16
nodejs: v14.15.4 | v10.15.0 (tried both)
yarn: v1.22.5
mysql: 5.7
web directory: /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/
[![browser screenshot: attached][1]][1]
```

After login, the screen locks with appearance of "Loading..."

I checked and found the following errors in the console and network tabs:

```
404: 
GET:http://akeneo.local/dist/vendor.min.js?0ab9c908450fca4dbe941c388f93d76e
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 42ms]
GEThttp://akeneo.local/dist/main.min.js?0ab9c908450fca4dbe941c388f93d76e

GEThttp://akeneo.local/dist/vendor.min.js?0ab9c908450fca4dbe941c388f93d76e
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 39ms]

GEThttp://akeneo.local/dist/main.min.js?0ab9c908450fca4dbe941c388f93d76e
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 46ms]
```

Also, getting multiple errors while running:

```
yarn run webpack

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1144,39)
      TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1144,45)
      TS1109: Expression expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1145,22)
      TS1109: Expression expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1145,38)
      TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1145,44)
      TS1109: Expression expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1146,21)
      TS1109: Expression expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1146,37)
      TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1146,43)
      TS1109: Expression expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/pim-community-standard/node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts(1148,1)
      TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I'm able to resolve this issue and successfully Akeneo setup on Ubuntu 16.04.

The versions older than 4.0 are NO more supported as per the official document.

I installed and setup "Akeneo PIM Community Edition v4.0" and follow each step of the official URL:

https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/system_install_ubuntu_1804.html

The tricky parts are:

```
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/akeneo-pim.local.conf
```

Thanks,